# An error with psycopg2 while trying to connect to a remote host server

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm writing a script that should connect to postgres DB.  My code is as follows:

```
import psycopg2
conn = connect(host="192.168.89.121")
```

But this is generating the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no hay una l�nea en pg_hba.conf para �192.168.89.3�, usuario �fgc�, base de datos �fgc�, SSL inactivo
```

Why is it asking for an entry for 192.168.89.3 which is my IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the remote PostgreSQL server? The error message appears to be trying to tell you that the configuration of that PostgreSQL server isn't allowing you to make an insecure connection. Look at the pg_hba.conf file for the database on that PostgreSQL server. It determines how different machines can connect to it. That's why it's mentioning your IP -- different rules can exist for different IP addresses.